# Eclipse’s Ctrl+click does not work and indexer does not seem to update?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am running Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Ganymede) and I have recently encountered a problem with it.

I can no longer get Ctrl+click navigation to work!

I went to my project and tried to rebuild the index, but the rebuild command of the indexer does not work either.  I did not do anything to my knowledge that may have caused this bug and so I was wondering if it could be a corrupt index or something else weird like that.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Though you may get someone who knows the answer, this is not really a programming question. You should try whatever support is available for eclipse or the appropriate plugin(s). There are probably forums, maybe a newsgroup that will be better able to assist you.
Checking the log may give you a stack trace to start with (Help>About>configuration details>view error log, depending on the version).

Answer (score 3):

First thing to do in such strange cases is to start eclipse with the -clean switch:

```
eclipse -clean
```

and see if it helps.

-- 
Uwe